# OpenGL ES 2.0 (or Marmalade SDK), and effect similar to order of "glRotate()", "glTranslation()" in OpenGL ES 1.x

Tags: matrix, opengl-es-2.0, marmalade

In OpenGL ES 1.x, one could do glTranslate first, and then glRotate, to modify where the center of rotation is located (i.e. **rotate around given point**). As far as I understand, in OpenGL ES 2.0 matrix computations are done on CPU side. I am using IwGeom (from Marmalade SDK) – a typical (probably) matrix package. From documentation:

> Matrices in IwGeom are effectively in 4x3 format, comprising a 3x3
>   rotation, and a 3-component vector translation.

I find it hard to obtain the same effect using this method. The translation is always applied *after* the rotation. More, in Marmalade, one also sets Model matrix:

```
IwGxSetModelMatrix( &modelMatrix );
```

And, apparently, rotation and translation is also applied in one order: a) rotation, b) translation.

How to obtain the OpenGL ES 1.x effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Marmalades` `IwGX` wraps `OpenGL` and it is more similar to `GLES 1.0` then `GLES 2.0` as it does not requires shaders.

`glTranslate` and `glRotate` modifying view matrix.

You may replace with

```
CIwFMat viewMat1 = IwGxGetModelMatrix();
CIwFMat rot; rot.SetIdentity(); rot.SetRotZ(.....); // or other matrix rotation function
CIwFMat viewMat2 = viewMat1; 
viewMat2.PostMult(rot); // or viewMat2.PreMult(rot);
IwGxSetModelMatrix(viewMat2);
// Draw Something
IwGxSetModelMatrix(&viewMat1);
```

If you use `GLES 2.0` then matrix might be computed in vertex shader as well. That might be faster then CPU. `CPU` with `NEON` instructions have similar performance on iPhone 4S

Comment: Can I ask for clarification? How to include the translation? Or, in other words, how to rotate around point (x, y, z)?

Comment: Here is your formula: `V2 = V1 * R * T`  I have not used IwGx for a while but I am almost sure that `M1 = M1 * M2` is `M1.PostMult(M2)` and `M1 = M2 * M1` is `M1.PreMult(M2)`.